# Prove that matrix A is invertible

Tags: matrices

So we have $\Bbb{K} \in \{\Bbb{R},\Bbb{C}\}$ with $n \in \Bbb{N}$, $n\geq 1$ and $u,v \in \Bbb{K}^n=\Bbb{K}^{n\times 1}$ as two column vectors. I need to prove that the $n \times n$-matrix $A := 1+uv^t$ is invertible if $u^tv\neq -1$ is true.

Comment: Please correct the notation so it will be easier for people to understand the question.

Comment: You can answer that for yourself after reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula

Comment: Thanks for the keyword. So, if u^t=-1, A is the zero matrix which is not invertible, because a matrix with Det(0) is not invertible. That simple?

Answer (score 1):

If $uv^t=0$ the result is trivial, so we can assume $u\ne0$. Using the fact that
$$
xy^tz=(y^tz)x
$$
(where in the right hand side we consider $y^tz$ as a scalar), prove that if a nonzero vector belongs to the null space of $A$, then $u$ belongs to the null space, which means …